# pycharm using custom ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pycharm

I need to acccess remote server as follow :
    Localmachine -SSH-> GateServer  -SSH-> Server_python

It seems proxyserver command is necessary as described below :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215986/ssh-login-with-a-tunnel-through-intermediate-server-in-a-single-command

However, how can I configure pycharm to do access the final SSH server through the gating ?
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html